# R: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph' get broken down with R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am getting varaible resutls in my keras tensorflow session in R. I would like to be more consistant for training my models. I have tried using use_session_with_seed() but it get the error

```
2019-12-15 17:46:31.057595: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'
```

Is there a package I can install with...

```
reticulate::py_install()
```

I am not sure if this help but when I import tensorflow and try tf$reset_Default_Graph i get an error

```
library(tensorflow)
tf$reset_default_graph()
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'
```

I'm running...
python 3.7
r 3.6.1
tensorflow 2.0
anaconda 
windows 10
gpu = nvidia 1060 with max q design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow 2.0 uses eager execution by default and doesn't include the `tf$reset_default_graph()` method. You can still find it in the `compat` module with `tf$compat$v1$reset_default_graph`.

Comment: Thank you!! You might want to add that here too: https://www.r-bloggers.com/simple-audio-classification-with-keras/ @Daniel Falbel